# TableView not displaying text with JSON data from API call

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I connected to API using `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJson`.

I got this JSON return:

```
{
"contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c202",
                "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
 ]
}
```

This is my ViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController:UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tblJSON: UITableView!

    var arrRes = [[String : AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getRequest()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getRequest() {
        Alamofire.request("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                if  let resData = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"].arrayObject {
                    self.arrRes = resData as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                }

                if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                    self.tblJSON.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: tableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrRes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
        var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["email"] as? String
        return cell
    }

}
```

I have trouble displaying result on the `UITableView`.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` `cellForRowAt` are this method get called ?

Comment: 1. Did you set the `ViewController` as the delegate and datasource of your tableView in the storyboard? 2. Did you set override `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returning 1 ?

Comment: You must call `reloadData` on the main queue.

Comment: @W.K.S There is no need to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView` if you only have one section. That is the default.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, I worded that badly: I meant has OP overridden the method and returned 0 because he thought there are no sections. It's a mistake I made when I was new.

Comment: @Rajat this methods didn't call.

Comment: @rmaddy what does it mean "call reloadData on the main queue" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to implement `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` like this

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

and in `viewDidLoad` you need to assign `DataSource` and `Delegate` to your tableView like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblJSON.dataSource = self
    tblJSON.delegate = self
    getRequest()
}
```

Comment: maybe you know, why TableView displaying only "name" although I write in code: cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String; cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["email"] as? String

Comment: `print(cell.detailTextLabel)` add this line in cellForRow and check if its not nil

Comment: xCode tell me that it's nil

Comment: Check if outlet for that label is connected or not

Comment: Outlet don't need. Because I use default label (open var textLabel: UILabel? { get } // default is nil.  label will be created if necessary.) My label created but my detailLabel don't created. I don't know why. I don't use UILabel in storyboard.

Comment: I found the solution. I went to StoryBoard. Click on Cell and change it from Custom style to Subtitle style. Thank you for your help