# Alamofire web service (API) swift 4

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm still new at JSON and `Alamofire`.
I have spent a day to understand and applied it to my project basically. The `API` structure is look like as below:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "amount": 20000,
            "amount_display": "200.00",
            "balance_amount": 20000,
            "account_balance_display": "200.00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "amount": 10000,
            "amount_display": "100.00",
            "balance_amount": 29000,
            "account_balance_display": "290.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to display `"id"`, `"amount_display"` and `"account_balance_display"` in `tableview` `cell`. But I really don't have any idea, even to read the json.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    var dict = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.lbl1.text = dict["id"] as? String
    cell.lbl2.text = dict["amount_display"] as? String
    cell.lbl3.text = dict["account_balance_display"] as? String
    return cell
}
```

and :

```
static let kdata = "data"
var responseArray: NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request("myURL").responseJSON { response in
        //print (response)

        if let balanceJSON = response.result.value {

            let dataObject:Dictionary = balanceJSON as! Dictionary<String, Any>
           // print(dataObject)

            let balanceObject = dataObject[TopupTableViewController.kdata] as! NSArray
            print (balanceObject)
        }
    }
}
```

this what I have already done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554279/tableview-not-displaying-text-with-json-data-from-api-call?rq=1

Comment: @UmaMadhavi tq...  :)

Comment: What you have done is just right. Make `array` used in your tableView's data source equal to `balanceObject ` is the simplest way.